# SQL related question for this querying statement

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I'm trying to understand what the question is trying to ask for, but I need help...

```
  employee table's columns: employee_id, name, manager_id
```

Since employees can be someone else managers, how do I suppose to count the subordinates of the manager?

What I think

```
      employee table corresponding to the stated columns 

         A1 : Ant : C1

         B1 : Bird : D1

         C1 : Cat  : E1

         D1 : Dog  : C1

         E1 : Elephant :B1
```

So how should the query or the queried display look like head counting the subordinates of the manager with the manager name as the first column?

Comment: You need a recursive or hierarchical query.  What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Please share the expected output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to count the number of subordinates of each manager, get the numbers with `group by "manager_id"` and `count(*)` and then join to the table to get the manager's name:

```
select e."name", m.counter
from (
  select "manager_id", count(*) counter 
  from employee
  group by "manager_id" 
) m inner join employee e
on e."employee_id" = m."manager_id"
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7c569e3222a575455757a03c58174bcc).
Results:

```
> name     | COUNTER
> :------- | ------:
> Bird     |       1
> Cat      |       2
> Dog      |       1
> Elephant |       1
```